# Как запускать несколько таймеров на android друг за другом?

Tags: android

Изучаю android, возникла потребность запустить **N** таймеров и все они должны отработать последовательно после нажатия кнопки(1ый отработал, стартанул второй и т.д.) без пауз, только если полная остановка всех таймеров. Есть список с количеством секунд. Сделал топорно по клику в отдельном потоке в цикле handler отправляет число оставшихся секунд и поток застывает на секунду, но кажется решение не очень профессиональное. А `CountDownTimer` никак не одолею, подозреваю, что в `onFinish` нужно стартовать следующий таймер, но как заставить цикл ждать. Буду рад мнению, как реализовать. Спасибо!

Comment: Какую задачу вообще решаете? Уверен, что можно обойтись одним таймером.

Comment: Задача написать приложение для тренировок. Нужно за 20 секунд сделать то-то, следом без пауз за 40 секунд сделать то-то. На экране стартуем таймер, оттикали 20 секунд автоматически запускается второй таймер на 40 секунд и т.д. Тут важно отсчет не суммы всех таймеров показывать, а каждого интервала.

Comment: вам легче Handler крутить каждую секунду

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать что-то типа такого

```
int ticks = 0;
int shownTicks = 0;

void startTimer() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            ticks++;
            shownTicks++;

            if (ticks == 20) {
                shownTicks = 0;

            } else
            if (ticks == 40) {
                shownTicks = 0;

            }
        }
    }, 60000);
}
```